# How do I write a sql REGEXP_REPLACE statement to only replace a particular section of a cell?

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I have a table value with multiple similar blocks on code I'm trying to do a search and replace on for a "src" value. The only value that differentiates these blocks is the "id". I'm stumped on how to construct the mysql statement. Here is the 'meta_value' cell content:

```
[av_image src='https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/09/replace_this.jpg' attachment='1252' align='center' id=''][/av_image]

[av_image src='http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/09/dont_replace_this.jpg' attachment='560' align='center' id='hero_img'][/av_image]
```

I have the following statement, but it replaces BOTH src strings.

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = REGEXP_REPLACE(meta_value, "src='[^']*'", "src='NEWURL'") WHERE post_id = 2 AND meta_key = '_aviaLayoutBuilderCleanData'
```

How do I modify the pattern in REGEXP_REPLACE to only replace the src in the [av_image] block with the id='hero_img'?

Comment: *How do I modify the pattern in REGEXP_REPLACE to only replace the src in the [av_image] block with the id='hero_img'?* Include this marker substring into the pattern. Exclude `]` from intermediate chars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `Positive Lookahead` to match only the string with `hero_img` in it:

```
(?=.*hero_img)
```

Combine it with what you have:

```
src='[^']*'(?=.*hero_img)
```

Regex [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/s8Itwa/1)

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta 
  SET meta_value = REGEXP_REPLACE(meta_value, "src='[^']*'(?=.*hero_img)", "src='NEWURL'") 
WHERE post_id = 2 AND meta_key = '_aviaLayoutBuilderCleanData'
```

Fiddle [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/7KlORf11).

**Result:**

| post_id | meta_key | meta_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | _aviaLayoutBuilderCleanData | [av_image src='https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/09/replace_this.jpg' attachment='1252' align='center' id=''][/av_image] [av_image src='NEWURL' attachment='560' align='center' id='hero_img'][/av_image] |

[Regex Lookahead Tutorial](https://www.regextutorial.org/positive-and-negative-lookahead-assertions.php)